# Problems tying onChange function to checkbox

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements

I'm trying to tie a function to an OnChange checkbox event. The error message I'm getting says that the doClick function I've created is not a function. I'm totally stuck here. My code ...

```
export class LocalGroupsTabContent extends React.Component {

  doClick(index, event) {
    this.props.click(index);
  }

  render() {
    let activeClass = this.props.activeId;

    let content = this.props.data.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <div className={'tabs-textItem ' + (activeClass === index ? 'show' : '')} >
          <div className="tabs-third-level-menu">
            <div className="container">
              {item.links.map((link, index) => {
                return (
                  <label key={ index } className="control control--checkbox">{link}
                    <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.doClick.bind(this, index)} />
                    <div className="control__indicator"></div>
                  </label>
                )
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    });

    return (
      <div className="tabs-content">{content}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the error being thrown on render or when you click on the item?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your doClick method, it is with the click method you have specified within it.

In this method:

```
doClick(index) {
 this.props.click(index);
}
```

The problem you have is that you have not specified a click method prop.

Either pass in a click method via the props (though I'd recommend instead using onClick handler), or handle the click event in your component. See my example here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/mo7j742kkj